# Array not being correctly passed from one class to another

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 form applications. One form application is calculating values and putting them in the array. The second form application takes these values and checks them, according to there value it draws something. According to the debugger, the 2 by 2 array is empty when it comes to the second form.

In reality, the two name spaces are in different files in visual studio and the using statements are all repeated for the second form window.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public const int SIZEX = 656;
        public const int SIZEY = 656;
            public static int[,] xinteracting = new int[SIZEX, SIZEY]; //Tells you the points at which it interacts with the different objects

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            xinteracting [0,0] = 1;
            //Your code goes here
            //Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
        }
    }
}
/*Second form window represented from here*/
namespace Hello 
{

        public class Yollow
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           Program old = new Program();
            int temp = old.xinteracting[0,0];
            Console.WriteLine( temp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For one thing, this won't compile because `xinteracting` is private. If you fix that, `Program.Main` is never called from `Yollow.Main`, so `xinteracting[0,0] = 1;` is never executed.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Sorry about that, i've turned the private into a public

Comment: @Blorgbeard Just picked up on the second thing said, should the main file from the initial form not be automatically executed? I mean in my real program i can check to see the value of the xinteracting funciton and after the entire form is finished i do check the values and they come up as the values i expect

Comment: No, the `Main` function is only automatically executed when it's the entry-point of the program.

Comment: I don't think `xinteracting [0,0] = 1;` is being called from the other `Main()` method. Can you debug to see if I'm right?

Comment: In addition to the comments about other flaws in your code, the expression `old.xinteracting[0]` can't compile because the `xinteracting` array is a two-dimensional array and so requires two indexes to get a value. It's also not necessary to create an instance of the `Program` class if it's a static member as shown here; you can access it easily with `Program.xinteracting`. But as other comments have noted, if you don't execute code to _change_ the array, you'll never see the array changed.

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu The main function is being executed. I know this because in the debugger, right before i call the other class (with the new windows form) i check to see the values of the xinteracting function and they are set. When i check to see any other value it doesn't give me any results

Comment: @PeterDuniho I've corrected the issue but i still can't get the right value, it just gives me a 0

Comment: You keep mentioning "windows form", but there is no such code in your question. Not a sign of any Winforms objects or code at all. You claim that the `Main()` method is executed; but there are _two_ in the code you posted and neither calls the other. So given the code you posted, at most only one could be called. Fix your question so that it includes a good [mcve]. At the moment, your question makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, when you create an instance of class Program, xinteracting is created, too, but Main method do not run, so that you receive an empty array.

My solution:

1. Create constructor in class Program => set `xinteracting [0,0] = 1;`
2. Because that array is static, you can get/set value directly from anywhere. Just call `Program.xinteracting[0,0] = 1` to set or `var value=Program.xinteracting[0,0];` to get

Comment: Have i not done that?
The program recognizes old.xinteracting[0,0], so i'm sure i'm doing that part right but the problem is, it's just not carrying the values from one form to another. It's just giving me a 0, when i debug it right before i call the new form the value is not a 0 (it's 100000)